# Rails 3 - how to show in form an image from database

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, helper

My form:

```
<%= form_for @optional, :html => {:multipart => true}, :validate => true do |f| %>
  <%= field_set_tag do %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label 'Description' %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :desc, :size => 60 %>
  </p>
...
  <p>
    <%= f.label 'Logo' %>
    <% if :logo %>
      <%= f.logo %> #bad idea
    <% else %> 
      <%= f.file_field :logo %> 
    <% end %>
  </p>

  <% end %>
```

I would like to ask you, how I can get the value of **:logo**. If I put **:logo** as parameter to **text_field** (<%= f.text_field :logo %>), I'll see the value of :logo (picname.jpg), but I don't know, how the value to show separately...

Any ideas, how to do?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add

```
<%= image_tag @optional.logo unless @optional.logo.blank? %>
```

You may need to adjust for your file structure.